# Failed to find init.goldfish.rc

Tags: adb

adb shows that I have  init.goldfish.rc present in the emulator device. I guess this file must exist somewhere in PC.  However I could not find the file in the PC. Why it is so?

Comment: AFAIK, init.x are initialization routines that a kernel depends on - Obvious isn't it? :) I am wondering why you have to look for those in your PC, unless you mean your PC runs Linux? Pardon, if that is the case...

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're looking for on your PC. If you're looking for the file from the emulator's filesystem then it's not going to be stored as a flat file on your PC - the emulator uses filesystem images.

Answer (score 1):

Do an `adb pull /init.goldfish.rc` and the file will be on your PC :-)

Comment: This answer. I like it. To go into a bit more detail, the file (and all other files in the virtual device) is stored inside the image that the emulator uses - not as an individual file on the PC.